# Filtering Pandas DataFrames on datetimes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Hello I need to get the date before 30 days, it is coming in this datetime format.

```
10/15/2020 4:34:27 AM    1970-01-01
10/15/2020 5:09:32 PM    1970-01-01
10/15/2020 5:01:32 PM    1970-01-01
10/15/2020 5:05:32 PM    1970-01-01
10/15/2020 5:03:32 PM    1970-01-01
```

Comment: cast the datetime strings using `pd.to_datetime` : see : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pd.to_timedelta`, like this:

```
In [1265]: df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['10/15/2020 4:34:27 AM', '10/15/2020 5:09:32 PM', '10/15/2020 5:01:32 PM', '10/15/2020 5:05:32 PM', '10/15/2020 5:03:32 PM']})

In [1266]: df
Out[1266]: 
                    Date
0  10/15/2020 4:34:27 AM
1  10/15/2020 5:09:32 PM
2  10/15/2020 5:01:32 PM
3  10/15/2020 5:05:32 PM
4  10/15/2020 5:03:32 PM

In [1273]: df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)

In [1274]: df['subtracted_date'] = df['Date'] -  pd.to_timedelta(30, unit='d')

In [1275]: df
Out[1275]: 
                 Date     subtracted_date
0 2020-10-15 04:34:27 2020-09-15 04:34:27
1 2020-10-15 17:09:32 2020-09-15 17:09:32
2 2020-10-15 17:01:32 2020-09-15 17:01:32
3 2020-10-15 17:05:32 2020-09-15 17:05:32
4 2020-10-15 17:03:32 2020-09-15 17:03:32
```